# Visual Studio Code, C/C++ Extension, include renamed path

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include-path

In the code I have:
`#include "xml/XMLParser.h"`

While that actual path to the 'XMLParser.h' is:
`${workspaceFolder}/lib/XML/XMLParser.h`

This folder structure causes VSCode to be unable to match the include (mismatched capitalization), and thus showing a red squiggle underline and not giving me nice intellisense.

Due to a convoluted build process, the directory gets aliased to its lowercase version during build, which then allows the compiler to find the header as written in the code. Thus, is there a way I can tell VSCode to do something similar when searching for matching includes?

I can't rename the folder name nor can I change the include to match the folder since this code is part of a very large project.

Comment: If you are on linux or other OS with case sensitive file systems the mismatched capitalization may be a problem.

Comment: Can't you do a search and replace? I mean replace `xml/XMLParser` with `XML/XMLParser` on all files in your project. If that does not work `#include "xml/` with `#include "XML/`

Comment: @drescherjm Yup, case sensitivity is the problem. And I also can't actually change the includes since I don't actually own that code. As stated above, it's part of a large team project, and the build system (hundreds of makefiles) handles the mismatched cases by making an alias to those headers.

Comment: Have you tried manually creating an alias and making that permanent (in the appropriate place in the workspace directory structure)?